# Catch logs of containers created by a Docker executor of a GitLab Runner

Tags: docker, logging, gitlab

Given a Docker Engine client (GitLab Runner) which creates and destroys containers dynamically through the Docker Engine API.

Constraints

- The `HostConfig.LogConfig.Type` is always set to `json-file` and can not be changed; see also https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/commit/aa96ed52c7a8bea6b6679d0bca682404bfed14e4.
- Docker Engine removes all JSON log files whenever the corresponding container is destroyed; the options `max-file` and `max-size` do not seem to affect that behavior.
- Log driver configuration of the Docker Daemon will always be overwritten by the client creating a container if given.

Please correct me if I'm wrong in one or more of the constraints above.

How could I catch the logs of the containers created by the GitLab Runner without:

- making a merge request to GitLab Runner or Docker Engine
- changing the image of the created containers

Background is, that GitLab Runner does not publish the logs of so called "service containers"; see also https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2119.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Docker Engine API. Write a program that:

1. attaches to the [event stream](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/SystemEvents)
2. attaches to the [log stream](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ContainerLogs) of already running containers
3. attaches to the [log stream](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ContainerLogs) of newly started containers
4. detaches from the [log stream](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ContainerLogs) of destroyed containers

Pipe e.g. the log streams as JSONL to STDOUT. Based on that you should have a lot of further options to proceed.

For 2. and 3. make sure that you use only containers which are using `json-file` or `journald` log driver.